# Mac OS/WebView: Why Flash and other plugins are not available when a local page is loaded?

Tags: flash, macos, webview

We are working on Objective C application for desktop Mac.

We use WebView component to display HTML pages.

When the page is loaded from the local file system, Flash movies are not displayed on the page.
As it turned out the problem is not exactly about Flash.
Most WebView plugins are missing.

[image: WebView plugins - local page is opened from the hard drive]

When the page is loaded from the Internet, Flash is displayed properly and there are many plugins available.

[image: WebView plugins - page is opened from the web]

The problem does not occur on my Mac, but it happens to 30% of our customers.
It is reproduced on MacBook (not MacBook air), Mac OS version is 10.5.8.

Guys, please help us, I have no idea how to tackle this.
This is the only obstacle preventing us from the product release.

Why WebView plugins are not available when a local page is loaded?

What can be the source of the problem - Safari configuration, Mac security settings, some software installed?

How can I reproduce the problem on my Mac?

This is our WebView initialization code for local page loading.

```
IBOutlet WebView* webView;
...

[[webView preferences] setPlugInsEnabled:YES];    
WebFrame *mainFrame = [webView mainFrame];

NSString* path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/page.html",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];  

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [mainFrame loadRequest:request];
```

Have you noticed any flaws?

UPDATE 1

[Test application](http://yowindow.com/perm/WebView.zip)

[Source code](http://yowindow.com/perm/WebView_src.zip)

UPDATE 2

Minimal test, I have left only the code necessary to open the local page.
No diagnostic window displayed.
[Test application, simple](http://yowindow.com/perm/WebView_simple.zip)

Full source code for Application Delegate of the simple test

```
#import "WebViewAppDelegate.h"

#import <WebKit/WebView.h>
#import <WebKit/WebFrame.h>

@implementation WebViewAppDelegate
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [[webView preferences] setPlugInsEnabled:YES];

    WebFrame *mainFrame = [webView mainFrame];
    NSString* path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/page.html",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];  

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [mainFrame loadRequest:request];

}

@end
```

Comment: Guys, help, we have been waiting for 2 weeks and there are not a single reply. Please, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok,

running v2 from the download failed, I still got the plugins alert and no crab

so I rebuilt the xcode project and included 10.5 as a target, then manually moved the html and swf into contents and it reports all the safari plugins and runs on 10.5.8

so although your plist says 10.5 [min] your sdk target was/is 10.6, so it won't run on 10.5

john

Comment: Thank you John, this must be the way. I have compiled the test against 10.5 SDK. Now I am waiting for our user to check if Flash is running in our test on his Mac.
I wonder why building against 10.6 SDK impacts the software. As you have noticed our target OS version is 10.5. Isn't it enough to guarantee stable running on 10.5?

Comment: I just have received testing result from our user. It works! John, thank you one more time for the help. The only thing that puzzles me is why compiling with SDK 10.6 and target OS 10.5 does not work on 10.5.8 I have checked your answer!

Comment: glad to be of help, I'm not very familiar with xcode, I just had a look at the options and gave it a go... I believe you can have multiple SDK targets, but if you only specify the latest anything older won't run.

Answer (score 2):

your plugins and alert may be blocking your linked js, the crab does not run in your webview here.

I can run the swf in another apps webview by pointing to the html file in package contents and that's without any 'plugins' enabled.

you might try adding WebKitDeveloperExtras booleen true to your prefs file so you can check with webinspector.

Comment: Thank you, driven, now I have a direction. Can you point me to the app you were testing our HTML with? I will update our test app tomorrow, will cut the code to minimum.

Answer (score 1):

I ran it in a Google 'SketchUp' WebDialog, the Nib file has the exact option settings as yours. If your unfamiliar with SU it has a Ruby Console available and you can write or serve html files to it. The free version and a little ruby is all that's required.
john

Comment: Hey, John, thank you so much for the help. It seems like you are our only hope :)) I have made a very simple test, see the update to the question. Please let me know if you can see the crab now.