# Why would Flash embeds show up as "Missing Plug-In" in a Cocoa WebView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

Building a very straightforward Cocoa app using Xcode 5. The main window is simply a WebView with plugins enabled that attempts to load a page from the Internet with a Flash embed on it.

Sandboxing is disabled and I've double- and triple-checked that plugins are enabled on the webview (both in the nib and programatically.) I've also tried running the app in both 32- and 64-bit modes.

Even navigating the WebView to the Adobe Flash website shows a missing plug-in box. What could cause the WebView object to not have Flash available?

Comment: Flash is not supported on any iOS device: http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that it is one of 3 options.

1. You do not have flash installed at all.
2. You have flash installed, but do not have the flash plug-in installed.
3. You have an old version of flash installed, and it has been disabled.

I have verified that it works (on my system) with a very small test:

[image]

```
NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.adobe.com/swf/software/flash/about/flashAbout_info_small.swf"]];
[[self.webView mainFrame]loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Grady -- are you running that test as a 64-bit app on OS X 10.8? Thanks

Comment: yeah this is a 10.8 normal install, 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the necessary WebView plugins are installed?
Is this only happening on your machine or can you replicate on another as well?

Maybe this post is helpful:

[Mac OS/WebView: Why Flash and other plugins are not available when a local page is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855165/mac-os-webview-why-flash-and-other-plugins-are-not-available-when-a-local-page)